# Virtualbox on Windows 10 Host crashed

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox

My PC is Windows 10 AMD Radeon r9 280x AMD FX 8350 Asus m5a78lm/usb3 motherboard, with 16GB RAM.

I'm using the latest VirtualBox version.

I was running Ubuntu 17.04 in virtual box and my whole PC crashed; i.e the host PC restarted with HARDWARE ERROR on Windows as it showed in reliability center. What can be the reason? I gave the VM 2048 MB of RAM, 2 cores, 32 Mb of video RAM and enabled 3D acceleration.

Error Details :

```
Description
A problem with your hardware caused Windows to stop working correctly.

Problem signature
Problem Event Name: LiveKernelEvent
Code:   141
Parameter 1:    ffffd80f336314a0
Parameter 2:    fffff805d5bff3dc
Parameter 3:    0
Parameter 4:    0
OS version: 10_0_14393
Service Pack:   0_0
Product:    256_1
OS Version: 10.0.14393.2.0.0.256.125
Locale ID:  1033
```

Error 2:(next time):

```
Description
A problem with your hardware caused Windows to stop working correctly.

Problem signature
Problem Event Name: LiveKernelEvent
Code:   141
Parameter 1:    ffffd68ede3e64a0
Parameter 2:    fffff80737b8f3dc
Parameter 3:    0
Parameter 4:    213c
OS version: 10_0_14393
Service Pack:   0_0
Product:    256_1
OS Version: 10.0.14393.2.0.0.256.125
Locale ID:  1033
```

Both errors came while I was running Ubuntu 17.04 in VirtualBox.

The PC restarts after this error automatically and crashes before restart.

Comment: Have you tried updating VirtualBox to the current version.  Earlier versions have problems with Windows 10 VMs

Comment: I did. I am running the latest version.

Comment: You didn't indicate that in your question.  You indicated the PC crashes, are you talking about the virtual machine or the host itself?  You should update your question and be specific.

Comment: disable HW acceleration for the guest

Comment: What leads you to believe the issue is with Virtual Box? If the host computer crashed, I wouldn't immediately suspect the virtual machine or hypervisor.

Comment: What will that exactly do Sir. And will it stop the errors?

Comment: Actually both errors came while I was using virtualbox and not during regular use.

Comment: HW acceleration uses host GPU, so if you get get a host crash while using a VM you should try it without HW acceleration

Comment: and what happened? Do you see new crashes or is your host PC now stable?

Comment: I ditched Virtualbox and now use VMWare Workstation and has not crashed since I started using it.So let's hope it doesn't crash again.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the user now switched to VMware and the question is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known bug in Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/16801), which is roughly 9 months old (if you dig through the [older bugs](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/16013) which where marked as duplicates of the newer bug). One (supposed) fix is to disable Hyper-V in BIOS.

Comment: disable hyper v IN BIOS?! I have no hyper v setting there. I have hyper v only as a windows feature. i did disable it but to no prevail.